# Java IllegalStateMonitorException while holding the lock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have written a class in java that implements a double buffer.
The class has two methods to write into the two buffers and a method to clear them.
Then I have three thread: one that writes on the first buffer, another that writes on the second buffer and a third one that clears the buffers.

Here, I paste (a piece of) the code that causes the problem (I know that it is not correct, but i've simplified it for debugging purposes):

```
public void addAlpha(int toAdd){
synchronized (alphaCount) {
    while(alphaCount >= alpha.length){
        try {
        alphaCount.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    alpha[alphaCount] = toAdd;
    alphaCount++;
    }
}
```

And here the piece in which i call the notifyAll():

```
public void clear(){
    synchronized (alphaCount) {
        alphaCount = 0;
        alphaCount.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the addAlpha method, I get the lock on alphaCount, test the condition and then wait on the alphaCount object.

In the clear method, i get the lock on alphaCount and I call notifyAll() on it.
At runtime, I get the IllegalStateMonitorException...

But I really don't know where the error is: I checked the documentation and more than one forum, without any luck...

Thanks for your time and your attention,
   Rick.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Answer (score 7):

As a rule, you should make field used as a lock `final` otherwise you can get bugs like this. IMHO You should make as many field final as you can. ;)

```
synchronized (alphaCount) { // alphaCount == 1 which is locked.
    alphaCount = 0;         // alphaCount == 0 which is not locked.
    alphaCount.notifyAll(); // fails.
}
```

Additionally I wouldn't recommend using Integer or String or any wrapper type for a lock. As there are many confusing and surprising consequences. e.g.

```
Integer i1 = 127;
Integer i2 = 127; // same object due to the auto-boxing cache.
i1 == i2;

Integer i1 = 128;
Integer i2 = 128; // not the same object.
i1 != i2; // may or may not be the same object depending on the cache size.
```

Another problem is that you could get a deadlock with a completely unrelated library which also happens to be using integer as a lock.

---

The solution is to use a dedicated lock object.

```
private final Object alphaCountLock = new Object();
private int alphaCount = 0; // don't use an object when a primitive will do.

synchronized (alphaCountLock ) {
    alphaCount = 0;
    alphaCountLock .notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

Just few seconds ago, I have been struck by the doubt that the bug is due to the fact that I'm using an Integer (that is unmutable and I don't remeber it when I write the code). 

The problem is, indeed, the one you stated in the second piece of code. To solve it, I have written a MyInteger wrapper and now all works fine.

Thank you so much for the reply! ^^

Comment: +1, nice answer, I did not think about the contents of the synchronized variable changing.

Comment: Its the object referenced which is locked, not the field. ;)

Comment: @RiccardoCipolleschi You might be interested in AtomicInteger ;) And the Exchanger for exchanging buffers between threads.